# How can I stage and commit all files, including newly added files, using a single command?

Tags: git

How can I stage and commit all files, including newly added files, using a single command?

Comment: The frustrating thing is that this used to be possible and was standard syntax to commit and add any new files: git commit -a But true to form, the git syntax changed. It confused existing users (and broke their scripts), eliminated useful functionality, and substituted an unnecessary flag.

Comment: There's a duplicate of this at [git add -A, git commit in one command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298960/git-add-a-git-commit-in-one-command). The accepted answer there is similar to the accepted answer here but suggests creating a git alias to shorten the typing involved (and shows how to do so).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git add and commit in one command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298960/git-add-and-commit-in-one-command)

Answer (score 710, accepted):

Does

```sh
git add -A && git commit -m "Your Message"
```

count as a "single command"?

### Edit based on @thefinnomenon's answer below

To have it as a `git alias`, use:

```sh
git config --global alias.coa "!git add -A && git commit -m"
```

and commit all files, including new files, with a message with:

```sh
git coa "A bunch of horrible changes"
```

### Explanation

From [`git add` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#git-add--A):

> -A, --all, --no-ignore-removal
>
> Update the index not only where the working tree has a file matching  but also where the index already has an
> entry. **This adds, modifies, and removes index entries to match the
> working tree.**
>
> If no `<pathspec>` is given when -A option is used, all files in the
> entire working tree are updated (old versions of Git used to limit the
> update to the current directory and its subdirectories).

Comment: what about the commit message ?

Comment: @NarendraJaggi git add -A && git commit -m "Your Message"

Comment: one could put that in it's own .sh or .bat file and just use it as one command. The message might be param1

Comment: And also you can add shortcuts for basic git commands in your .bashrc:

 alias gpl='git pull'
 alias gps='git push'
 alias gc='git commit'
 alias gs='git status'
 alias gd='git diff'
 alias ga='git add'
 alias gck='git checkout'
 alias gb='git branch'
 alias gl='git log'
 alias lcp='git format-patch -1 HEAD'
 alias resetToMaster='git reset --hard origin/master'

Comment: In powershell replace "&&" for ";" to run both commands, like this: `git add -A ; git commit -m "Your Message"`

Comment: I just wanted the modified files. Thus I used `git reset` to undo `git add -A`.

Comment: I tried creating alias on Mac but I'm getting an error "expansion of alias 'coa' failed; 'git' is not a git command".

Answer (score 482):

This command will add and commit all the modified files, **but not newly created files**:

```sh
git commit -am  "<commit message>"
```

From `man git-commit`:

```
-a, --all
    Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified
    and deleted, but new files you have not told Git about are not
    affected.
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, in fact specifically (in bold no less) excludes one of the key parts of the sought for solution.

Comment: Doesn't add or commit untracked files.

Comment: But it covers most typical situation when you commit after "git add -A" and notice that you forgot to change something small in code. I hate to write the same commit message several times from the scratch

Comment: but the thread starter says ALL FILES, so, I think this one does not count

Comment: And also you can add shortcuts for basic git commands in your .bashrc:

 alias gpl='git pull'
 alias gps='git push'
 alias gc='git commit'
 alias gs='git status'
 alias gd='git diff'
 alias ga='git add'
 alias gck='git checkout'
 alias gb='git branch'
 alias gl='git log'
 alias lcp='git format-patch -1 HEAD'
 alias resetToMaster='git reset --hard origin/master'

Answer (score 58):

Not sure why these answers all dance around what I believe to be the right solution but for what it's worth here is what I use:

#### 1. Create an alias:

```bash
git config --global alias.coa '!git add -A && git commit -m'
```

**NOTE**: The `!` preceding the `git add -A` command is required for this to work. You can read about why, and more on Git aliases here: [git-scm.com | 2.7 Git Basics - Git Aliases](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases)

#### 2. Add all files & commit with a message:

```bash
git coa "A bunch of horrible changes"
```

**NOTE**: `coa` is short for commit all and can be replaced with anything your heart desires

Answer (score 28):

I use this function:

```
gcaa() { git add --all && git commit -m "$*" }
```

In my zsh config file, so i can just do:

```
> gcaa This is the commit message
```

To automatically stage and commit all files.

Comment: for bash-like
`function gcaa() {
    git add --all && git commit -m "$*" && git push
 }
`

Comment: @Damilola - what do you mean by *bash-like*? the syntax in the answer works in bash as well

Answer (score 27):

One-liner to stage ALL files (**modified**, **deleted**, and **new**) and commit with comment:

```
git add --all && git commit -m "comment"
```

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit

Comment: one-liner, but not a single command (which is what the OP asked)

Answer (score 9):

Committing in git can be a multiple step process or one step depending on the situation.

1. This situation is where you have multiple file updated and wants to
   commit:

   You have to add all the modified files before you commit anything.

   ```
   git add -A
   ```

   or

   ```
   git add --all
   ```
2. After that you can use commit all the added files

   ```
   git commit
   ```

   with this you have to add the message for this commit.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want a "quick and dirty" way to stash changes on the current branch, you can use the following alias:

```
git config --global alias.temp '!git add -A && git commit -m "Temp"'
```

After running that command, you can just type `git temp` to have git automatically commit all your changes to the current branch as a commit named "Temp". Then, you can use `git reset HEAD~` later to "uncommit" the changes so you can continue working on them, or `git commit --amend` to add more changes to the commit and/or give it a proper name.

Answer (score 5):

Run the given command

```sh
git add . && git commit -m "Changes Committed"
```

However, even if it seems a single command, It's two separate command runs one by one. Here we just used **`&&`** to combine them. It's not much different than running 
`git add .` and `git commit -m "Changes Committed"` separately. You can run multiple commands together but sequence matters here. How if you want to push the changes to remote server along with staging and commit you can do it as given,

```sh
git add . && git commit -m "Changes Committed" && git push origin master
```

Instead, if you change the sequence and put the `push` to first, It will be executed first and does not give desired push after staging and commit just because it already ran first.

`&&` runs the second command on the line when the first command comes back successfully, or with an error level of 0. The opposite of `&&` is `||`, which runs the second command when the first command is unsuccessful, or with an error level of 1.

Alternatively, you can create **alise** as **`git config --global alias.addcommit '!git add -a && git commit -m'`** and use it as **`git addcommit -m "Added and commited new files"`**

Answer (score 4):

I have in my config two aliases:

```
alias.foo=commit -a -m 'none'
alias.coa=commit -a -m
```

if I am too lazy I just commit all changes with

```
git foo
```

and just to do a quick commit

```
git coa "my changes are..."
```

coa stands for "commit all"

Comment: I would hate to work with a repository filled with commit messages saying "none", and I'd reject any PR's on that basis as well. Unfortunately, the only way you can learn the importance of having good commit messages is when you have to go back to audit something written a long time ago ("this line is causing a bug... why was it even added, and will anything break if I change/remove it?").

Comment: Commits with "none" are never intended to stay for long. Normally I start my own feature branch, do micro commits and squash them into something more reasonable before a merge. Obviously people who do commits for each modified function and do not mind a full blown git log do not need this.

Comment: I use 'wip' (short for "work in progress") instead of 'none' for this purpose and I only push such commits to my private branches.

Comment: It's still unhelpful, because eventually those "wip" or "none" commits will make it into a branch that other people see, and will pollute the message log. If you're squashing all of your commits before you push then that would be acceptable but it's otherwise still annoying for the team.

Comment: Not an aswer since it does not commit newly added files

Comment: A lot of people (unfortunately) use version control as a journaling file system and don't write commit messages (or use some useless generic ones). This makes it very hard for others to work on the code in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Great answers, but if you look for a singe line do all, you can concatenate, alias and enjoy the convenience:

`git add * && git commit -am  "<commit message>"`

It is a single line but two commands, and as mentioned you can alias these commands:

`alias git-aac="git add * && git commit -am "` (the space at the end is important) because you are going to parameterize the new short hand command.

From this moment on, you will be using this alias:

`git-acc "<commit message>"`

You basically say:

git, add for me all untracked files and commit them with this given commit message.

Hope you use Linux, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

try using:

```
git add . && git commit -m "your message here"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the most elegant way to stage and commit all changes:

```
git commit -am  "message"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a small script (look at Ian Clelland's answer) called `git-commitall` which uses several git commands to perform what you want to do.
Place this script in your anywhere in your `$PATH`. You can call it by `git commitall` ... very handy!

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347901/what-are-your-favorite-git-features-or-tricks/402878#402878) (question and all answers unfortunately deleted, only visible with high reputation)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [shell script](https://github.com/grwlf/git-powercommit) which does a somewhat close thing. Currently it doesn't commit newly added files (it should be easy to add this feature), but it does commit everything else. Also, it visits Git submodules recursively. The intended usage scenario is as simple as

```sh
$ git powercommit
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the following command to `add` and `commit` the changes with one command:

```
git commit -a -m "your commit message"
```

***CAUTION***: This will not commit untracked files

Comment: This will not commit untracked files.

Comment: @Friedrich thanks, I forgot to mention that. The answer is now updated