# How can I commit everything that's changed in my git repo with just one command?

Tags: git, alias, commit, git-commit, one-liner

I want to commit all of the changes in my repository with **one command**.

I know I can do it with two—using `git add -A` and then `git commit -a`—but, as a wise man once said... [why waste time say lot word when few word do trick?](https://youtu.be/VvPaEsuz-tY).

Is there not an `-A` option for `commit` like there is for `add`?

Comment: It was my first hit for *git add and commit everything*

Answer (score 1):

There is *not* an `-A` option for `commit`. [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759533/5432315) say it would do more harm than good, committing files you didn't know were there.

However **you can** still do what you're looking to do: commit it all with just **one command**.

### One command land, here we come!

You can turn any number of commands into one with something called **[an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553786/how-do-i-alias-commands-in-git)**—it's just another name that you can tell git to recognize as a command—you just need to **define it**. What you name the alias is up to you.

Aliases you could create

- ✅ `git ca`, if you want brevity; `ca` standing for "**c**ommit **a**ll" or
- ✅`git commit-all` to match existing git conventions.

You can't make an alias that looks like this

- ❌`git commit -A` because git alias names [can't have spaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48862/how-can-i-create-an-alias-for-a-git-action-command-which-includes-spaces)

### Here's how

To **add an alias**, open up your user-level git configuration by running
`git config --global --edit`

Then, under the `[alias]` section, **add this line**:

```
[alias]
    ca = !git add -A && git commit -av
```

The `!` [allows multiple commands](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Sending_multiple_messages_from_a_single_file) in an alias.

Finally, **save and close** the file.

### A word of warning

Tadah! Now you can run `git ca` to add and commit all the changes in your repository.

*However*, using this puts you at risk of committing things you didn't intend to commit, so **proceed with caution**. Good luck!

Here's [a list of other useful aliases](https://githowto.com/aliases) you might consider.

Comment: "Alias names can't have spaces" is a weird way to put it, arguments in general can't have spaces because (un-quoted/-escaped) spaces *separate* arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @jonrsharpe. The intended audience might not be experienced enough to realize that; all they know is that they want the same functionality as `add -A`, but in `commit`—which might've lead them to try to use `commit -A` as an alias.