# Git commit all files

Tags: git, git-svn

How can I commit the full project again? (I want upload all of my file upload again to heroku)

Comment: Possible duplicate...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419249/git-commit-all-the-files-using-single-cmd

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
git add .
git commit -a
```

not completely sure what you want, but to add all files and commit all changes, use this

Comment: I want readd all files, because I think my git slug is corrupted

Answer (score 3):

> I want readd all files, because I think my git slug is corrupted

I'm not sure what you mean by corrupted -- Git uses SHA1 hashes, and it's very very hard for things to break.

You could do `find | xargs touch` just in case your mtimes got messed up, but after that, `git status` will show you reliably if your working copy matches the repo (minus anything listed in `.gitignore`).  Generating a new commit without any changes (which is what you seem to be asking for), as with `git commit --allow-empty`, is verifiably going to get you the same tree and won't solve your problem.

So I think you'll have to bite the bullet and spend some time tracking down where exactly the corruption happened (track down broken files, see which commit changed them, etc.).  It's most likely not Git's fault.