# Why does 'git commit' not save my changes?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-commit, git-status

I did a `git commit -m "message"` like this:

```
> git commit -m "save arezzo files"
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   arezzo.txt
#       modified:   arezzo.jsp
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

But afterwards, when I do `git status` it shows the same modified files:

```
> git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   arezzo.txt
#       modified:   arezzo.jsp
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `git commit -am "save arezzo files"` to automatically add all changes (w.r.t. .gitignore). You may want to add only specific files/dirs: `git add file.src`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419249/git-commit-all-the-files-using-single-cmd http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571106/git-commit-all-files

Answer (score 419, accepted):

As the message says:

> no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Git has a "staging area" where files need to be added before being committed, you can [read an explanation of it here](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/18/the-staging-area.html).

For your specific example, you can use:

```
git commit -am "save arezzo files"
```

(note the extra `a` in the flags, can also be written as `git commit -a -m "message"` - both do the same thing)

Alternatively, if you want to be more selective about what you add to the commit, you use the **[git add](http://gitref.org/basic/#add)** command to add the appropriate files to the staging area, and **[git status](http://gitref.org/basic/#status)** to preview what is about to be added (remembering to pay attention to the wording used).

You can also find general documentation and tutorials for how to use git on the **[git documentation page](http://git-scm.com/documentation)** which will give more detail about the concept of staging/adding files.

One other thing worth knowing about is **[interactive staging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging)** - this allows you to add *parts of a file* to the staging area, so if you've made three distinct code changes (for related but different functionality), you can use interactive mode to split the changes and add/commit each part in turn. Having smaller specific commits like this can be helpful.

Comment: @PeterBoughton did you mean "interactive adding" instead of "interacting adding"?

Comment: Nah, I meant interactual adding.

Comment: Local repository is a kind of a staging area itself before pushing code to remote repository. Why add a yet another "layer" before commiting changes, isn't it a bit overcomplicated? I'm new to git but I imagine 99,99% developers always use commit -am because the changes don't go outside their local environment anyway.

Comment: I think I just ran into this because I'm used to my IDE taking care of it for me.  Not sure why it's a necessary step either, but then again, there's a lot about git I don't get... I mean git...

Answer (score 53):

You didn't add the changes. Either specifically add them via

```
git add filename1 filename2
```

or add all changes (from root path of the project)

```
git add .
```

or use the shorthand `-a` while commiting:

```
git commit -a -m "message".
```

Comment: In addition, I strongly urge users to use interactive adding. Especially when you're trying to make nice small commits that are easily reversible.

Answer (score 45):

You should do:

```
git commit . -m "save arezzo files"
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer to the OP's question. He didn't want to "add", he wanted to commit what was modified.

Answer (score 10):

I copied a small sub project I had that was under Git source control into another project and forgot to delete the .git folder. When I went to commit I got the same message as above and couldn't clear it until I deleted the `.git` folder.

It is a bit silly, but it is worth checking you don't have a .git folder under the folder that doesn't commit.

Answer (score 7):

You could have done a:

```
git add -u -n
```

To check which files you modified and are going to be added (dry run: -n option), and then

```
git add -u
```

To add just modified files

Answer (score 6):

The reason why this is happening is because you have a folder that is already being tracked by Git inside another folder that is also tracked by Git. For example, I had a project and I added a subfolder to it. Both of them were being tracked by Git before I put one inside the other. In order to stop tracking the one inside, find it and remove the Git file with:

```
rm -rf .git
```

In my case I had a WordPress application and the folder I added inside was a theme. So I had to go to the theme root, and remove the Git file, so that the whole project would now be tracked by the parent, the WordPress application.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe an obvious thing, but...

If you have problem with the index, use [git-gui](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui). You get a very good view how the index (staging area) actually works.

Another source of information that helped me understand the index was Scott Chacons "Getting Git" page 259 and forward.

I started off using the command line because most documentation only showed that...

I think git-gui and gitk actually make me work faster, and I got rid of bad habits like "git pull" for example... Now I always fetch first... See what the new changes really are before I merge.

Answer (score 4):

I find this problem appearing when I've done a `git add .` in a subdirectory *below* where my `.gitignore` file lives (the home directory of my repository, so to speak).  Try changing directories to your *uppermost* directory and running `git add .` followed by `git commit -m "my commit message"`.

Answer (score 2):

if you have more files in my case i have 7000 image files **when i try to add them from project's route folder it hasn't added** them but when i go to the image folder everything is ok. Go through the target folder and command like abows

```
git add .
git commit -am "image uploading"
git push origin master
```

> > git push origin master Enumerating objects: 6574, done. Counting objects: 100% (6574/6574), done. Delta compression using up to 4
> >     threads Compressing objects: 100% (6347/6347), done. Writing objects: 
> >     28% (1850/6569), 142.17 MiB | 414.00 KiB/s

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where I was doing `commit --amend` even after issuing a `git add .` and it still wasn't working.  Turns out I made some `.vimrc` customizations and my editor wasn't working correctly.  Fixing these errors so that `vim` returns the correct code resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue with the same error message. "Changes not staged for commit", yet when I do a diff it shows differences.  I finally figured out that a while back I had changed a directories case. ex. "PostgeSQL" to "postgresql".  As I remember now sometimes git will leave a file or two behind in the old case directory.  Then you will commit a new version to the new case.

Thus git doesn't know which one to rely on.  So to resolve it, I had to go onto the github's website. Then you're able to view both cases.  And you must delete all the files in the incorrect cased directory. Be sure that you have the correct version saved off or in the correct cased directory.

Once you have deleted all the files in the old case directory, that whole directory will disappear. Then do a commit.

At this point you should be able to do a Pull on your local computer and not see the conflicts any more.  Thus being able to commit again.  :)

Answer (score 0):

if you have a subfolder, which was cloned from other git-Repository, first you have to remove the $.git$ file from the child-Repository:
`rm -rf .git`
after that you can change to parent folder and use `git add -A`.

Answer (score 0):

delete each .git file in all projects

you can use this command

```
rm -rf .git
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning, If you are Using Git 2.40 or 2.41 (Q1/Q2 2023), even a `git commit -am` can still generate:

```
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

This is reported in [`git-for-windows/git` issue 4462](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/4462)

> The crucial part to make it fail was to ensure that no tracked file is left after staging the deletions
>
> ```bash
> mkdir test_repo
> cd test_repo
> git init
> echo test > file1.txt
> echo test > file2.txt
> git add --all
> git commit -m "first commit"
> del file1.txt
> del file2.txt
> git commit -m "remove files" -a
> ```

This is fixed with Git 2.42 (Q3 2023).

A few places failed to differentiate the case where the index is truly empty (nothing added) and we haven't yet read from the on-disk index file, which have been corrected with Git 2.42 (Q3 2023).

See [commit 2ee045e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2ee045eea103e8818ffe0c4085fad3f6b535c8d6), [commit 7667f4f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7667f4f0a3c2002940c0b03930597fddc8599277), [commit 866b43e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/866b43e6442f16d0073ae9ce8d79b6cb1161b1a9) (29 Jun 2023) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7f5ad0c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f5ad0ca8d1d7db7a21755af34251714d86b2ec1), 08 Jul 2023)</sup>

> ### [`commit -a -m`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2ee045eea103e8818ffe0c4085fad3f6b535c8d6): allow the top-level tree to become empty again
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> In [03267e8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/03267e8656c23cf1e2d1df8204d4cee236fb0077) ("`commit`: discard partial cache before (re-)reading it", 2022-11-08, Git v2.40.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ea1378d046d764642718f1b070689072bde4601) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c2ef319c52c4997256f5807564523dfd4acdfc7)), a memory leak was plugged by discarding any partial index before re-reading it.
>
> The problem with this memory leak fix is that it was based on an incomplete understanding of the logic introduced in [7168624](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7168624c3530d8c7ee32f930f8fb2ba302b9801f) ("Do not generate full commit log message if it is not going to be used", 2007-11-28, Git v1.5.4-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/31cbb5d96151891491168d3f813e6898c9ef825b)).
>
> That logic was introduced to add a shortcut when committing without editing the commit message interactively.
> A part of that logic was to ensure that the index was read into memory:
>
> ```
> if (!active_nr && read_cache() < 0)
>   die(...)
> ```
>
> Translation to English: If the index has not yet been read, read it, and if that fails, error out.
>
> That logic was incorrect, though: It used `!active_nr` as an indicator that the index was not yet read.
> Usually this is not a problem because in the vast majority of instances, the index contains at least one entry.
>
> And it was natural to do it this way because at the time that condition was introduced, the `index_state` structure had no explicit flag to indicate that it was initialized: This flag was only introduced in [913e0e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/913e0e99b6a6e63af6a062622a1f94bd78fd8052) (`unpack_trees()`: protect the handcrafted in-core index from read_cache(), 2008-08-23, Git v1.6.1-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6096f17d2d5d9ccb453aabf8edc6ee238b166fc)) `(unpack_trees()`: protect the handcrafted in-core index from `read_cache()`, 2008-08-23), but that commit did not adjust the code path where no index file was found and a new, pristine index was initialized.
>
> Now, when the index does not contain any entry (which is quite common in Git's test suite because it starts quite a many repositories from scratch), subsequent calls to `do_read_index()` will mistake the index not to be initialized, and read it again unnecessarily.
>
> This is a problem because after initializing the empty index e.g. the `cache_tree` in that index could have been initialized before a subsequent call to `do_read_index()` wants to ensure an initialized index.
> And if that subsequent call mistakes the index not to have been initialized, it would lead to leaked memory.
>
> The correct fix for that memory leak is to adjust the condition so that it does not mistake `active_nr == 0` to mean that the index has not yet been read.
>
> Using the `initialized` flag instead, we avoid that mistake, and as a bonus we can fix a bug at the same time that was introduced by the memory leak fix: When deleting all tracked files and then asking [`git commit -a -m ...`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2ee045eea103e8818ffe0c4085fad3f6b535c8d6/Documentation/git-commit.txt#L67)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--a))</sup> to commit the result, Git would internally update the index, then discard and re-read the index undoing the update, and fail to commit anything.