# How to push my update changes to the repository

Tags: php, json, git

I cloned my repository from github and then updated the composer by adding

```
composer install
```

So I believe the composer.json page has been updated with new lines of code. I want to push it back to github online repository .

How Can I do this , I tried doing

```
git commit
```

It give me following message

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   .env.example
        modified:   composer.json
        modified:   config/app.php
```

So changes to these files like composer.json , .env , config/app.php will not be effected on the online repository ??

Any insight on this please

Thanks

Comment: `git add .` first before commit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does git commit not save my changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704480/why-does-git-commit-not-save-my-changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to follow this .

From your git repository.

1. `git add .`
2. `git commit -m "Comment Here"`
3. `git push origin master`

Comment: @Loremlpsum Actually me and my friend both are using same repository to push and pull and we both are new to this , So If I made a change and pushed it , then before he starts working he need to pull right ? , Also can you tell the pull comment also

Comment: @Vikram yes your friend needs to pull first by using `git pull origin master`.

Comment: `git pull` means updating your repository. to make your repo **up-to-date** with its remote version.

Comment: yes he/she needs to pull first to avoid conflict when he/she will going to push again.

Comment: @madforstrength when my friend pulled the repository every page has been commented , May I know why its happening like that

Comment: @madforstrength now if he does `git pull origin master` its showing can't pull because it has unmerged file

Comment: @LoremIpsum any insight on the above comments ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
git add .
```

Before:

```
git commit
```

`git add .` will stage all files for commit. If you want a specific file to be staged than you can do `git add file_name`

Ref: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add