# Git add and commit successful, but does nothing

Tags: git

I got the solution to my problem here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23087593/5253746

But, I want to know why the problem occurs. I added image files to .gitignore. Then, I made some new folders with code and images. I decided to remove the image files from .gitignore.

From a sub-folder in my repository`, I did git add .`, `git commit -m "message"`, `git push` which were successful. When I did `git status` I see the same git status before the commit/push.

Why does this happen ?

Comment: What is that status? Does it show any of the files in that subfolder, as modified or otherwise? Can you include the output of `git status` for that directory into your question?

Comment: Well what did `git status` show you right before the commit?  It sounds like the `git add .` did not work, possibly owing to the `.gitignore` file or something else.

Comment: When you say 'git push was successful', what do you mean? Can you share output of 'git add .', 'git commit -m "message"' and 'git push' commands?

Comment: `.` refers to the current folder and it's subdirectories, that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
git add .
```

means add '.' folder to the staging area. since you are in a subdirectory, it won't work.

You could try `git add ../` from the sub-directory to add all files from the parent directory. Checkout 'pathspec' from options from [this page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)

Comment: As per the qustion text, @HelloWorldNoMore already tried "git add ." command.