# git add " Nothing specified nothing added "

Tags: git, command-line, repository, addition, commit

I'm new to using git and I'm getting a bit confused. What I'm trying to do is set up a new repository for a particular project folder. My first question is where exactly do I need to be filewise in the terminal, Desktop or the Folder itself to initialize the files. I tried navigating to the actual folder and typed in `git status` which listed the files as untracked so I typed `git add` to stage for commit which came up with "Nothing specified, nothing added.
Maybe you wanted to say 'git add"

Not sure where I have gone wrong.

Comment: You need to specify which files you want to add. Eg: `git add filename.js` or `git add .` to add all files.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed cheers man

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does git commit not save my changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704480/why-does-git-commit-not-save-my-changes)

Comment: This error message was originally written by Shakespeare

Answer (score 8):

Please use `git add .` instead of `git add`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"git add ."` or `"git add -A"` instead of `git add`.

`"git add"` moves the changed file from the working directory to the staging area (git add file name with extension), while `"git add -A"` moves all the changes to the staging area.
It does the same thing as `"git add -all"` or `"git add.` , `git add -u"` put together.

- `"git add"` keeps track of new files and changes without deleting
  anything (on the current directory and its subdirectories).
- `"git add -u"` puts changes and deletions in order without creating new
  files.

So, `"git add -A"` is a valuable way to do both things quickly.