# Github unable to push

Tags: git, github

I have added a folder on my mac to the GitHub folder repository and now I have a problem with committing.

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
    modified:   iOS-Dev-2.0/Xcodes Tutorial/.DS_Store
    modified:   iOS-Dev-2.0/Xcodes Tutorial/first-full-app-window-shopper-source (modified content, untracked content)
    modified:   iOS-Dev-2.0/Xcodes/Test01/Test_01 (modified content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I tried a few things via terminal first of all
`cd iOS-Courses` - this is the directory where iOS-Dev-2.0 is stored
`git add *`
`git push origin master`

Comment: And what is the problem you have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does 'git commit' not save my changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704480/why-does-git-commit-not-save-my-changes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error/ warning message itself tells you the further steps.

You need to add the changes into staging area using `git add` command.
then perform commit operation with your commit message using `git commit -m "your commit message"` command.

Git works as distributed version control system where for every code you have local copy and you perform all the operations such as add/remove/stash/commit. Unless you `commit` and `push` (literally push into remote repository) the changes are only on your machine.

May be you need to take a look at how git basic operations works.

1. [Saving changes](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes)
2. [git commit](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-commit)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `commit` before pushing anything.

`add` add your changes/files to the `index/stage` that will be put in the `commit`.