# Command for adding all files in git status -uno

Tags: git

I am trying to add all files that is tracked. `git add .` seems to add all files regardless of tracking status. Is there a git command for adding all files in `git status -uno`?

Comment: use this `git add -A`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git commit all files using single command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419249/git-commit-all-files-using-single-command)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between "git add -A" and "git add ."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add)

Comment: @zaratustra `git add -A` actually adds all files (include untracked files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git add -u` (or `--update`) will add any file that was previously tracked by git. `git add -A` will add all the the files, including those that weren't previously tracked.