# How to add untracked files to commit in git?

Tags: git

I recently added a new site to my laravel as an e-commerce. When I try to push this site to my production server I get an error about it not being tracked.

When I run git status I get this:

```
C:\Users\Kye\sites\laravel>git status

On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

        modified:   e-commerce/demo (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

When I try to add the folder, and files:

```
git add e-commerce/demo -A
```

It still doesn't work and says its untracked. How can I commit this change and add the files?

```
C:\Users\Kye\sites\laravel>git add .

C:\Users\Kye\sites\laravel>git add -A

C:\Users\Kye\sites\laravel>git commit -m "test"
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   e-commerce/demo (modified content)

no changes added to commit

C:\Users\Kye\sites\laravel>git push
root@54.38.214.9's password:
Everything up-to-date

C:\Users\Kye\sites\laravel>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I stage and commit all files, including newly added files, using a single command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419249/how-can-i-stage-and-commit-all-files-including-newly-added-files-using-a-singl)

Comment: If you want to add all the modified files you can use `git add .`

Comment: Appreciate the comment @Vyacheslav but that doesn't work either.

Comment: It seems `e-commerce/demo` is a nested repo or a submodule.

Comment: it is @ElpieKay, can I remove the nested repo?

Comment: I deleted the `.git` file in the `demo` dir and now I get `fatal: 'e-commerce/demo/.git' not recognized as a git repository` @ElpieKay when I do `git add .`

Comment: I don't know how your project is organized, so I can't tell. I'd suggest you read instructions about submodules.

Comment: The nuke option could be helpful? remove all .git foldesr from your project and re init and either force push or delete and create a new repo. I realize this isn't the optimal solution but it may help? Just a thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

> ```
> Changes not staged for commit:
>         modified:   e-commerce/demo (modified content)
> ```

means that you already have a submodule.  Specifically, the `(modified content)` is the giveaway.

When a superproject uses a submodule—as in this case—the superproject itself is a Git repository, and the submodule is another, mostly-independent Git repository.  The superproject has a few crucial control files:

- `.gitmodules` contains information the superproject Git needs so as to run `git clone` to get the submodule repository to exist.  This stuff is only needed once!
- `.git/config` contains information the superproject Git has squirreled away *after* running `git clone` so that the submodule now exists.

This second file also, of course, contains all the information the superproject repository needs to do `git fetch` and `git push` to the Git repository from which you cloned the superproject.

Note that because the submodule *is* a Git repository, it has its own `.git`, containing its own `.git/config`.  This tells the submodule how to `git fetch` and `git push` to the Git repository from which the submodule Git was cloned (by the superproject Git).  At this point, there are *four* interesting repositories:

- Your own superproject: this Git repository, in which you've run `git status`.
- The Git from which you cloned your superproject: your `origin`.
- Your own submodule: the Git where your superproject did `(cd path; git status)` (more or less) and found that there was something modified.
- Your own submodule's `origin`, from which your submodule was cloned.

In general, here is how you deal with changes you make in the submodule:

1. Commit them in the submodule Git, somewhere—preferably to a branch.  This part is pretty easy, once you're very familiar with Git.
2. Send them to whoever controls the upstream of this submodule.  This may involve creating a fork of some project on GitHub, for instance.  This part is a little harder, but is just the same as you do on any repository where there is an upstream, so once you're very familiar with Git, it's not hard.
3. Convince the owners of the upstream of the submodule to accept your changes.  If you own this upstream yourself, that's pretty easy: just convince yourself to take your own changes.  If someone else owns it, you may have to do a lot of convincing, and you might end up committing something different, after however much back-end-forth it takes.  This part is often *very hard!*  It depends on the upstream.

   (Or, of course, you can just use your fork in the future, i.e., *change* the URL you store in the `.gitmodules` and `.git/config` of the superproject.  After you do that, you own the upstream, and you just have to convince yourself, which as we just saw, is probably a lot easier.)
4. Now that these changes are committed in the upstream repository, you can rely on them in future clones, so that's all good.  Use `git checkout` in your submodule to get the right commit checked out.  Use `git fetch` there if you need to, to pick up the correct commit from the upstream.  Make sure that `git rev-parse HEAD` prints out the *right* commit hash ID at this point, because that's what we're about to use.  Remember that Git is all about **commits** and their **hash IDs**.  Branch names are only important in terms of letting us find hash IDs.
5. Finally, *now* you can run `git add e-commerce/demo` in your superproject.  When you make your *next* commit in the superproject, your Git will record the hash ID of the commit to check out from the submodule.

#### Why is this so hard?

The reason we did all this stuff in steps 1-4 is not to make *your current* repositories work.  (We could do that much more simply.)  It's to make *future clones of the superproject* work.

In the future, someone will run:

```
git clone <url for superproject>
```

This will get them a clone that has a `.gitmodules` file.  In that `.gitmodules` file, they will have *another* URL, that specifies how to clone the submodule.

Next, they will run `git checkout` if necessary (if they want a particular commit or branch or whatever), and then `git submodule update --init` to make *their* Git clone the submodule, as directed by the `.gitmodules` file.  That will use the URL stored in `.gitmodules`, and will copy information into their `.git/config` for their superproject clone.  **The last step of this `git submodule update`** is that their Git will look at the current commit to see **what hash ID** to `git checkout` in the submodule.  Their superproject Git will, at this point, do the equivalent of `(cd submodule; git checkout hash)`, putting their submodule onto the commit that you managed to save in your step 3.  You *recorded* that hash ID in *your* superproject Git at step 5; you *got* that hash ID ready in your step 4; but you got that hash ID into the *upstream* repository in step 3.

*You* already had a commit you could use, but when future-person future-clones the superproject, they don't have your submodule yet.  They get a copy of `.gitmodules`, which gives them a URL for another `git clone`.  They run another `git clone` and get a submodule repository.  The submodule they get comes from *their* upstream, as directed by the `.gitmodules` file; *that* clone needs to *have* the commit whose hash ID you record in your step 5, when you make your superproject commit.

That's what makes this hard.  It's why some people refer to these as *sob*-modules. :-)  It really does all work, it's just complicated.  It's not that bad if you control the submodule's upstream.