# git alias to stash then reset (what does !git mean?)

Tags: bash, git

I need a git alias to stash then reset.

Which one should I use in my .bashrc:

```
git config --global alias.sr '!git stash && git reset --hard HEAD'
```

or,

```
git config --global alias.sr 'git stash && git reset --hard HEAD'
```

I am asking this because [How can I stage and commit all files, including newly added files, using a single command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44531921/1772898) used `!git` and I am not sure what that actually means amd it confused me to use one or the other.

Comment: @L3viathan I think this qualifies for an accepted answer. So, can you please put it in the answer section.

Comment: This question is really about the `!` in the alias. But I will add this comment: the alias shown is pointless. That's because the last step of `git stash` is to run `git reset --hard HEAD`. Running it a second time does not produce anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `git-config` manpage:

```
If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it
will be treated as a shell command. For example, defining alias.new
= !gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD, the invocation git new is equivalent
to running the shell command gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD. Note that
shell commands will be executed from the top-level directory of a
repository, which may not necessarily be the current directory.
GIT_PREFIX is set as returned by running git rev-parse
--show-prefix from the original current directory. See git-rev-
parse(1).
```

So you'll need to use the form with a `!`. If no `!` is present, git will interpret the value as a git-subcommand, e.g. `git config alias.foo 'bar'` will make `git foo` equivalent to `git bar`. Since you use a shell feature (the `&&`), you need to route it through the shell with `!`.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer explains the shell escape, but it misses one important point: You do not need to put either of these commands in your `.bashrc`! The command `git config` stores the alias persistently in your git configuration. You just need to execute it once, and `git sr` will be understood -- also across reboots.

Comment: I actually do not put anything in my `.gitconfig` because I use bare repo to track my dotfiles and I can not track the `.gitconfig` with the bare repo. It messes things us when I try to restore.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean about the bare repo, but how do you _keep_ `git config --global` from saving the setting in your `.gitconfig`?

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. I do not need to put `git config --global alias.sr '!git stash && git reset --hard HEAD'` on my `.bashrc`. I just need to run it once in my terminal. Is it what you meant?

Comment: yes, exactly @blueray. This command writes the alias into your .gitconfig .