# Is there any way to have git automatically add empty directories?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I understand I can create .gitignore files in directories and then add the directories, and those files to the project. However:

- Is there a way of adding directories without having files in them?

  - Apparently not, but one can programmatically create empty files in empty directories https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463044/recursively-create-empty-file-in-empty-sub-directories
- Is there a way of automatically adding new files and/or directories whenever they are created, rather than running the `git add` command?

  - Apparently not, but one can programmatically add files, add a commit message, and push all in a single script [How can I stage and commit all files, including newly added files, using a single command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419249/how-can-i-stage-and-commit-all-files-including-newly-added-files-using-a-singl)

Comment: "Is there a way of adding directories without having files in them" No. Git knows nothing of directories. A commit contains only files with their pathnames.

Comment: As for your other question, does this answer it? [How can I stage and commit all files, including newly added files, using a single command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419249/how-can-i-stage-and-commit-all-files-including-newly-added-files-using-a-singl)

Comment: There is one trick that works to store an empty directory: use [the empty-repository submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58543445/1256452). (I don't really advise using it; a `.gitignore` or `.gitkeep` empty file is usually a better idea.)

Comment: @torek that looks like it changes directories into submodules, which seems a bit overkill in terms of complexity, but thank you for pointing out this option.

Comment: *seems a bit overkill* That's one reason I don't really recommend it. Submodules in general are painful. If Git's index could store directory entries, Git could store empty directories in commits; that would be better.

Answer (score 0):

As stated Git track directories only if it contains at least one file, so a well accepted pratice is to add an hidden file called `.gitkeep`.

About the second question, the answer is NO, you have to add the `.gitkeep` in order to track the directory.

Comment: This answer was helpful as it has a script that creates empty files if the directories are empty: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463044/recursively-create-empty-file-in-empty-sub-directories